# How to get mahout and neo4j in a same java project?

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, mahout

This is part of my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The ERROR is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I found the mahout needs  lucene-core 4.6.1, but the neo4j using neo4j-lucene-index 2.2.1, what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's common problem. Neo4j 2.3 uses old version of the Lucene (3.6.2). In JVM you aren't able to use two different version of same library.

You have few options how to deal with it, but you should not use them in the production.

1. Create your own Class Loader.
2. Maven Shade plugin

Comment: I just copy [plugin part](https://github.com/lagodiuk/neo4j-uber-jar/blob/master/pom.xml) into my pom.xml, but it does not work.